# Creating an object copies old

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I have multiple canvas setup in my HTML page. I access them via their respective ID in JS/jQuery.
In this canvas there is a "player"-character (a basic square), that has a constant size and a variable position.

I create the player object like this:

```js
<script>
var player = {
    xpos = 50,
    ypos = 50
}  
</script>
```

in the same `<script></script>` I have a function that looks like this:

```
async animate(cid2){
var c = Object.create(player);
cid = $(cid2)[0];
ctx = cid.getContext("2d");
c.xpos = 50;
c.ypos = 50;
while(c.xpos < 300){
    await sleep(1100);
    c.xpos = c.xpos + 50;
    //draw a rectangle..
}
```

Once any `<canvas id="test">` is clicked, (with a jQuery .click Function), animate is executed with the respective canvas id.

All of this works great, as long as there is one canvas on the page.
If I have say two canvas, the following happens in the console:

```
canvas1 is clicked!
X-Position: 50
X-Position: 100
canvas2 is clicked!
X-Position: 150
X-Position: 200
```

Although the second canvas is clicked and a `Object.create` should create a new object, it doesn't work: It still accesses the old object.

I am almost certain there is an answer to this on SO, but despite my best efforts, I can't find it, because I don't know what is actually going wrong.

Can anyone help me or refer me to a question I could ask?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your `var player` assignment is not correct syntax. Object syntax is `{xpos: 50, ypos: 50}`

Comment: To copy an object use `Object.assign()`, not `Object.create()`. `Object.create()` is for creating an object that inherits from another object's prototype.

Comment: @Barmar you are right, I just mistyped it here

Answer (score 0):

You could use the (I think ECMAscript 6) spread operator

```js
const obj = { myProp: 'hi' };
const newObj = { ...obj };
newObj.myProp = 'ciao';
console.log(obj); // still { myProp: 'hi' }
```

Know you should have two separate objects instead of a copy.